# AWS Personalize throws bad param error using context={...}

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-personalize

I am working with AWS Personalize and the Python SDK (boto3).  All goes well until I try to include the context param in the request.  While everything works as expected within the Personalize > Campaigns UI for testing the results, when I try to use the following code:

```
response = personalizeRt.get_recommendations(
campaignArn = 'arn:aws:personalize:XXXXXXXXXX:campaign/interactions-meta',
userId = '43f0c7fd-4d89-4752-9c88-2fe5bf7ac830',
context={
    'GENRES' : '42'
}
```

)

I get the following error:

```
Unknown parameter in input: "context", must be one of: campaignArn, itemId, userId, numResults
```

Has anyone else seen this error?  And if so, how did you resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing a similar error. using context in SIMS did you tried it?? is it working only with HRNN or with all. I know it is an old question but could you help bout cases using context. thnkx

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue is the version of boto3/botocore within Pycharm.  If I run the same code on the command line, all works as expected.

In Pycharm go to Preferences > Project Interpreter. and you can update boto3 there.